# Tacoma Power Steering Pump

Tags: power-steering, tacoma

I have a 2006 Toyota Tacoma.  Real nice truck-bought it new.  Seldom any problems or repairs.  It has 96,000 miles-very well maintained.
   A month ago, I had a "mechanic" replace my belt.  I picked up the truck-everything seemed to be OK.  **The very next morning** my power steering doesn't work right.  It seemed to work after I drove a little...and then it didn't work at all.  The "mechanic" said I need a new power steering pump.  All of a sudden? This all sounds a little suspicious to me.  Does it seem suspicious to any of you people that know more than me about this?  Could he have screwed up the supply of the fluid somehow? Your opinion is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any noise? Is the fluid level low? How's the belt tension? It may just be coincidence.

Comment: The pump has already been replaced.  There was no noise before it was replaced.  The belt seems OK.